# How to make a complete flat dump of all of the source in a git repo?

Tags: git, export

What's the best way to dump all of the source files in a git repo (from the HEAD) to a flat text file? I'm asking before I write something that just enumerates through all of the files and builds a little header from the filenames, because I figure there is a nicer tool out there I just can't locate.

The intended use is to submit the code in the appendix of a published document (a PDF generated from XeLaTeX/org-mode) for posterity.

Comment: I don't think git knows about latex. Perhaps you could use `git show` and wrap it in a shell script?

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the TeX part, or I would have asked a question over on TeX.SE. I can make it look nice with Markdown or emacs org-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has mentioned any existing tools, so [I've started work on one](https://github.com/talexand/gitscroll).

The algorithm I'm using is this:

1. `git ls-files` with filtering by file extension
2. Join filename and file with newlines
3. Add some brief markup from desired output format